# Is a normal distribution a good model of stock market returns across time?

Tags: modeling

I'd like to use something like numpy.random.normal to model random stock market returns for a given year, with mean of 7.25% and standard deviation of 19.8% (found using Excel), using numbers for the S&P 500 acquired here:

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/datafile/histretSP.html

Is a normal distribution a good model of stock market returns across time?

Comment: This is probably a better question for the [quant.SE] or [economics.SE] sites than here.

Comment: OK, should I delete and move there, or leave this one open?

Comment: You can flag this for the moderators to migrate the thread to whichever you prefer. Since this has now been answered, it doesn't seem fair to me to delete. Note that only the moderators can migrate this thread to either of those sites.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  That is because stock returns exhibit what is called 'fat tails'.  Google "fat tails" + "stock returns" and you will get lots of information.  I think that understanding analytically the returns of the market is a superb question that is obviously not know - at least not known publicly !